# What is the format for .ics attachment for the organizer, and where will it show while adding it in Google calendar

Tags: java, icalendar

I have the format created like the following, but I'm unsure where this organizer will show up on the Google calendar.

```
SUMMARY:Test Event
ORGANIZER;CN=Test:MAILTO:test@test.com
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:20181018T141500
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:20181018T151500
```

[image]

Comment: Try it and report back

Comment: Why is it related to Java ?

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238492/writing-ics-ical-file-using-java)

Comment: I have added this code in my java file to do this. I want to check if there is something wrong I'm doing and want some suggestions. ```ical.append("ORGANIZER;CN="+organizer+":MAILTO:"+organizerEmail);
ical.append("\r\n");```

Comment: Adding this code sometimes does not show the "Add to Calendar" option in Gmail.